# On Plone 4.3.15, how to install latest Stripe's API

Tags: python-2.7, stripe-payments, plone, setuptools, plone-4.x

On Plone 4.3.15 (Universal installation), it is not possible to install stripe 2.32.1.
See logs :

```
Getting distribution for 'stripe==2.32.1'.
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'project_urls'
  warnings.warn(msg)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
  warnings.warn(msg)
error: Setup script exited with error in stripe setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers
An error occurred when trying to install stripe 2.32.1. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing instance.
  Getting distribution for 'stripe==2.32.1'.
Error: Couldn't install: stripe 2.32.1
```

It seems that easy_install / Setuptools is too old ?
Do I need to upgrade Setuptool ? If so, how can it be done ?

Answer (score 1):

> 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers

Yes, your `setuptools` is too old. To upgrade:

```
pip install -U setuptools
```

Perhaps you also need to upgrade `pip`:

```
pip install -U pip setuptools
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I try it, didn't change anything... Seems that it comes from zc.buildout : /Users/jseb/Sites/zope/z_aster/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py

Comment: [`zc.buildout-1.7.1`](https://pypi.org/project/zc.buildout/1.7.1/) was released in 2013! Definitely time to upgrade.