# setup.py's install_requires - how do I specify python version range for a specific dependency?

Tags: python, version, setuptools

I'm working on a python project and the package supports python 3.6 - 3.10.

There were these 2 lines in the `install_requires` list in `setup.py`:

```
        "numpy>=1.18.5, <=1.19.5; python_version=='3.6'",
        "numpy>=1.19.5; python_version>='3.7'",
```

And I tried to change them to

```
        "numpy>=1.18.5, <=1.19.5; python_version=='3.6'",
        "numpy>=1.23.1; python_version>='3.10'",
        "numpy>=1.19.5; python_version>='3.7', <'3.10'",
```

And when I ran `python setup.py install`, I got this error:

```
$ python setup.py install
# yeah, I know `pip install .` is a better command.

error in mypackage setup command: 'install_requires' must be a 
string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Parse error at "", <'3.10"": Expected string_end
```

I tried some different variants to specify a `python_version` range of 3.7 to 3.9, but none of them worked.

So how do I specify python version range for a specific dependency in `setup.py`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56992111/7976758 Try to upgrade `setuptools`. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+install_requires+must+be+a++string+or+list+of+strings

Comment: @phd I'm already on setuptools 65.0.1.

Comment: Then I think `pip install .` is the only way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to [Complete Grammar](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/#complete-grammar), you can use `and` to achieve your purpose.

```py
"numpy>=1.18.5, <=1.19.5; python_version=='3.6'",
"numpy>=1.23.1; python_version>='3.10'",
"numpy>=1.19.5; python_version>='3.7' and python_version<'3.10'",
```